# How do i use jQuery to insert before first div with multiple div and no id or classes?

Tags: jquery

Example HTML

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I would like the new HTML to look like this

```
<div>NEW DIV APPENDED HERE</div>
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I have tried both below , but the new div gets added to all the div and not just before the first one.

```
$("div:first-child").before('<div>NEW DIV APPENDED HERE</div>');

$("div:nth-child(1)").before('<div>NEW DIV APPENDED HERE</div>');
```

Comment: You don't use `id`or `class`on your code ?

Comment: ofc i do , but i'm just adding something to an existing 3rd party site and i don't have access to edit the original HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`first-child` selects all divs that are the first childs of something, and that includes the first childs of the parent divs in your code.

To select only the first div in the collection, use `:first`

```
$("div:first").before('<div>NEW DIV APPENDED HERE</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use :eq(0) as it refers to the very first div in your result.

```
$("div:eq(0)").before("<div>One Above Them All</div>");
```

Please refer to this fiddle:
[JSFiddle to insert first DIV](http://jsfiddle.net/hjo9ezj7/)